# ArangoDB: How to limit/skip results with Javascript graph functions?

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb

I'm new to ArangoDB and I'm working on a Foxx service using the Javascript graph module. I see in AQL that the results of a graph traversal can be limited and offset, but I don't see the equivalent capability in the Javascript API (i.e. _neighbors function). Since there could be large numbers of neighbors involved, I hope there is a way to do this that doesn't require the full results of the neighbors function to be filtered by my script. Is there a lower level edge iteration approach that would allow me to build the result set directly?

Thanks!

Comment: In an attempt to answer my own question, I examined the server source code and didn't see any accommodations for offset/limit on neighbor or edge functions. I was actually quite surprised to find that the edge functions actually got translated into AQL queries. I would have expected tighter integration between server-side Javascript and the C++ graph engine. Are there plans to improve this area?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the javascript graph functions; they don't scale.

Please use [the AQL graph support](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs.html) instead.

AQL can be invoked via [`db._query`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/foxx-getting-started.html#writing-database-queries) from foxx services easily.

You can then further examine the results and reduce them to your needs in .js inside the foxx service.